Clarification Needed on 1D Convolution and Kernel Purpose
I am confused about the definition of 1D convolution.
Given $ a = [-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}] $ and $b = [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1] $, what will be the result of the convolution $( a * b )$?
From my understanding, the length of $ a * b $ should be $ 2 + 6 - 1 = 7 $. I tried converting the vectors into polynomials for easier calculation:
$ a = -\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2} $
$ b = x^5 + x^4 + x^3 - x^2 - x - 1 $
Multiplying them gives:
$ -\frac{1}{2}x^6 + x^3 - \frac{1}{2} $
So, $ a * b = [-\frac{1}{2}, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -\frac{1}{2}] $
However, I am not sure if this is correct because I tried it in ChatGPT, and it gave a completely different output:
ChatGpt Convolution Computation
In this context, the kernel is $ a$.
Could anyone help explain this kernel's purpose and clarify the convolution's correct result?

You computed the convolution correctly. ChatGPT does not know math. Just because ChatGPT says something is true, does not mean you should believe it.
